# Centering a GObject in Java

Tags: java, eclipse-neon, acm-java-libraries

since I am completely newly learning Java right now I have a serious problem which is hopefully easy to solve.

I need to create the olympic rings for a course which should show up centered on the screen.

Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import acm.graphics.*;
import acm.program.*;

public class OlympicRings extends GraphicsProgram{
    public void run() {
        GOval blueRing = new GOval (100, 100, 90, 90);
        blueRing.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        add(blueRing);
        GOval yellowRing = new GOval (150, 150, 90, 90);
        yellowRing.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        add(yellowRing);
        GOval blackRing = new GOval (200, 100, 90, 90);
        add(blackRing);
        GOval greenRing = new GOval (250, 150, 90, 90);
        greenRing.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        add(greenRing);
        GOval redRing = new GOval (300, 100, 90, 90);
        redRing.setColor(Color.RED);
        add(redRing);

        GCompound olympics = new GCompound();
        olympics.add(blueRing, 100, 100);
        olympics.add(yellowRing, 150, 150);
        olympics.add(blackRing, 200, 100);
        olympics.add(greenRing, 250, 150);
        olympics.add(redRing, 300, 100);



        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        double x = (screenSize.getWidth() - olympics.getWidth()) / 2;
        double y = (screenSize.getHeight() + olympics.getHeight()) / 2;
        add(olympics, x, y);
    }
}
```

Not pretty, I know, but it's only my 3rd code.

My problem: I don't get the GCompound centered. It always shows up on the far right bottom corner of the canvas.

I already searched through this site and plenty of others to find a solution but nothing worked.

I hope somebody can help me with this.

Kind regards,
Kate